# Notepad++ move the end of a line to the front

Tags: regex, csv, replace, notepad++

I have a csv file with movie data but some of the titles have the starting word at the end of the title for example

```
281,River Wild, The 
282,Time to Kill, A
```

need to be

```
281,The River Wild
282,A Time to Kill
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the solution was to use a regular expression

```
,(.+?), (.+?)$
```

and the replace with

```
,$2$1
```

and click on regular expression and wrap around